# Use divergence theorem to find $\iint_S (2x+2y+z^2) dS$ Where $S$ is the sphere $ x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, vector-analysis

I tried a lot but it gets ugly really soon, any help will be greatly appreciated.

T hanks

Comment: When $S$ is the unit sphere, $\int_{S} (2x+2y+z^2) dS = \int_{S} \vec{V}\cdot d\vec{S} $ where $\vec{V} = (2,2,z)$. Now what is $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{V}$?

Answer (score 1):

The divergence theorem is:
$$\iint_{\text{Surface of volume}} (\mathbf F \cdot \mathbf n)dS = \iiint_{\text{Volume}} (\text{div }\mathbf F)dV$$

On the unit sphere we have $\mathbf n = (x,y,z)$.

Find a suitable $\mathbf F$ and substitute it in the formula.